# Date won't display in my specified textView

Tags: android

So I've looked at A LOT of questions here, searching and searching for an answer to no avail.

My issue is that nothing is displayed in the textView: myDateTimeTextView.
I want the current date to be shown.

here's the code:

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public class currentDateTime extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{
    protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
        TextView myDateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myDateTextView);
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        myDateTextView.setText(currentDateTimeString);
        String Format = "EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY";
        Date today = new Date(); SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(Format, Locale.ENGLISH); System.err.format("%30s %s\n", Format, sdf.format(today));

    return currentDateTimeString;
    }
    }
```

Before I was having the app crash on me when I opened it. I found (via this site) that I should run it as an AsycTask. That fixed the crashing problem, but a new one has arisen: It doesn't display the date.

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
Thank you :)

**EDIT 1**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    new currentDateTime().execute();

}

public class currentDateTime extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    TextView myDateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myDateTextView);
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        String format = "EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY";
        Date today = new Date(); SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH); System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(today));

    return currentDateTimeString;
        }
        @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String currentDateTime) {
            myDateTextView.setText(currentDateTime);
        }   
}
```

So, you're all basically telling me to do the same thing and this was the only way I saw that didn't give me any errors under my declared variables (My app still crashes on launch). 
For instance: If I move 
`TextView myDateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myDateTextView);` to anywhere other than where it is currently, I get errors on the line saying it's not in use, and then errors under `onPostExecute()` saying it cannot be resolved.

I'm stuck :(

**EDIT 2**

```
   @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new      PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
//  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 //   DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY");

  //  TextView myDateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myDateTextView);
 //   String currentDateTimeString = format.format(calendar.getTime());
   // myDateTextView.setText(currentDateTimeString);


    new currentDateTime().execute();

}

   public class currentDateTime extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    TextView myDateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myDateTextView);
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        String format = "EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY";
        Date today = new Date(); SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.ENGLISH); System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(today));

        return currentDateTimeString;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String currentDateTime) {
        myDateTextView.setText(currentDateTime);
    }   
    }
```

And here's the LogCat

`06-14 07:26:15.483: D/gralloc_goldfish(856): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-14 07:26:16.173: W/dalvikvm(856): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validateFormat(SimpleDateFormat.java:264)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:319)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:365)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.mikitz.baalpha1blank.MainActivity$currentDateTime.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:49)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at com.mikitz.baalpha1blank.MainActivity$currentDateTime.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-14 07:26:16.203: E/AndroidRuntime(856):  ... 4 more
06-14 07:26:18.983: I/Choreographer(856): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-14 07:26:20.454: I/Process(856): Sending signal. PID: 856 SIG: 9`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your `onCreate()` method in last:

```
new currentDateTime().execute();
```

and also Add  `onPostExucute()` method in `AsynTask` class with following code.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

     myDateTextView.setText(result);

}
```

Remember remove  `myDateTextView.setText()` from `doInbackGround()` it will cause exception

Comment: Implement my code and put logcat, then i'll able to get the situation.

Comment: See Edit 2 for LogCat of your implementation

Answer (score 0):

You need to update you UI in `onPostExecute()` method

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 myDateTextView.setText(result);
}
```

And you can call your `AsyncTask` on `onCreate()` like

```
new currentDateTime().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your AsyncTask like this in onCreate()

```
new currentDateTime().execute();
```

Before calling intialise your textview in onCreate()

`myDateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myDateTextView);`

Change `public class currentDateTime extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>`

to

```
public class currentDateTime extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>  // as you're not passing anything while calling AsyncTask.
```

Change

`protected String doInBackground(Object... arg0)`

to

`protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0)`

And after `doInBackground` add the `onPostExecute()`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 myDateTextView.setText(result);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work? What is happening? If it is crashing then please post the logcat. And try moving `TextView myDateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myDateTextView);` after `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)`

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use asyncTask. You can try to do this:

```
@Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY");

    TextView myDateTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myDateTextView);
    String currentDateTimeString = format.format(calendar.getTime());
    myDateTextView.setText(currentDateTimeString);

    }
```

You are also doing something wrong. Your variable name is "Format" which is wrong because this is a class name. you should change it to "format".

```
String Format = "EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY";
```

to

```
String format = "EEEE, MMMM dd, YYYY";
```

Comment: I tried your method, but I receive and error "calendar cannot be resolved" even after importing `java.util.Calendar`

Comment: @Mikitz06 sorry my wrong, I edited the answer, add Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); to your code.